# How to avoid the field name in the LDAP SEARCH?

Tags: java, ldap

I am making an LDAP search application. And its working fine, but in the search results, it also gives me the field name

ex:

```
**sn:** YYYY
**department:** xxxx
....etc
```

How can I avoid printing the field names?

Thanks

```
public LdapContext getLdapContext() {

LdapContext ctx = null;
try {
        Hashtable<String, String> env = new Hashtable<String, String>();
        env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,
                "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "XXX");
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "XXXX");
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "XXXX");
        env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "XXXXX");
        ctx = new InitialLdapContext(env, null);
        System.out.println("Connection Successful.");
    } catch (NamingException nex) {
        System.out.println("LDAP Connection: FAILED");
        nex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return ctx;
}


SearchControls constraints = new SearchControls();

constraints.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);
String[] attrIDs = { lastName, firstName, location,
                     telephoneNumber, jobTitle, division };
constraints.setReturningAttributes(attrIDs);

// First input parameter is search base, it can be
// "CN=Users,DC=Domain,DC=com"
// Second Attribute can be uid=username
NamingEnumeration<SearchResult> answer = ctx.search("OU= Users,DC=Domain,DC=com",
                "sn=" + lastname, constraints);
```

some codes to show what I'm doing,,,pls help

Comment: I am using JAVA,,,Windows xp,,Working on the Liferay Portal,,,Eclipse IDE,,,Tomcat Server

Comment: There is no code here that prints anything except the connection failure. Difficult if not impossible to help you if you won't disclose what the code looks like.

Answer (score 0):

LDAP does not have fields, it has `attribute descriptions` which have attribute values. The attribute descriptions are aliases for OIDs, for example, `cn` and `department`.

In your code that displays the attributes, call the method that returns just the value of the attribute.

Also, consider using the [UnboundID LDAP SDK](https://www.unboundid.com/products/ldap-sdk/) instead of JNDI. JNDI should not be used for new code.

#### see also

- [LDAP: Programming practices](http://www.ldapguru.info/ldap/ldap-programming-practices.html)

Answer (score 0):

I can only assume your doing something along the lines of this:

```
static void printAttrs(Attributes attrs) {
   if (attrs == null) {
     System.out.println("No attributes");
   } else {
    /* Print each attribute */
    try {
     for (NamingEnumeration<?> ae = attrs.getAll(); ae.hasMore();) {
      Attribute attr = (Attribute) ae.next();
      System.out.println("attribute: " + attr.getID());

      // print each value
      for (NamingEnumeration<?> e = attr.getAll(); e.hasMore(); System.out.println("value: " + e.next()));
     }

    } catch (NamingException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

If you want to take parts of it, you can parse the content with something like:

** Note: this code was taken from somewhere, I lost the link...

```
/*
 * Prepares and returns CN that can be used for AD query
 * e.g. Converts "CN=**Dev - Test Group" to "**Dev - Test Group"
 * Converts CN=**Dev - Test Group,OU=Distribution Lists,DC=DOMAIN,DC=com to "**Dev - Test Group"
 */
public static String getCN(String cnName) {
    if (cnName != null && cnName.toUpperCase().startsWith("CN=")) {
        cnName = cnName.substring(3);
    }
    int position = cnName.indexOf(',');
    if (position == -1) {
        return cnName;
    } else {
        return cnName.substring(0, position);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the `get` method to get an object without the field name.

For example:

```
System.err.println(attribs.get("cn")**.get()**);
```

Thanks